# Creating a setter method for an enum

Tags: java, enums, setter

I need to create a method that sets the value of an enum attribute of an object. This is my code:

```
public void setSpecialization(VehicleType specialization) {
    Specialization = specialization;
}
```

both variables are of the same type, how am I supposed to assign the value? Because I keep getting `null` values in the field.

Comment: Probably you have a typo here and you're doing `specialization = specialization`. If so, try using the `this` keyword in your `attribute` and assign the `specialization` parameter to the `specialization` field of your class like this: `this.specialization = specialization`. If this is not the problem, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have show (other than starting a field name with an upper case letter)  Most likely the problem is int he code you haven't shown.  Can you give a simple example which reproduces the problem?

Comment: show use the whole class especially the member declaration

Comment: If the class is large, then don't show the whole thing lest we get drowned in code unrelated to your problem. Better as @LuiggiMendoza suggested would be for you to create an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small compilable and runnable program that reproduces your problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special with regard to this because `specialization` is of an `enum` type. It works in exactly the same way as with any other type:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private VehicleType specialization;

    public void setSpecialization(VehicleType specialization) {
        this.specialization = specialization;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note: Inside the method, `this.specialization` refers to the member variable; `specialization` refers to the argument variable.